# Remove "binary"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

> I heard computers use binary. My question is about computers, so I tagged it "binary".

[binary](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/binary)

Comment: In some cased "binary" probably refers to `[executable]`

Comment: @slhck: …which is also a horrible tag IMHO

Comment: Been there, [done that](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8160/do-we-really-need-the-executable-or-exe-tags).

Comment: @slhck: Heh, nice.

Comment: Add [executable-binary] or [native-executable-binary]?

Comment: @galegosimpatico: I don't see how they would be useful. But they're better than [binary], sure.

Comment: Questions tend to be binary. They are either answerable, or not.

Comment: It's thinking of linkage, `[static-executable-binary]` and `[dynamic-executable-binary]`, however they must be enough documented in Stack Overflow and are topics indeed very well documented outside SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No questions tagged [binary](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/binary) left!

There were a handful which actually pertained to `binary` in the sense of "How do I represent 256 in binary"; and others relating to hex-to-decimal conversion which needed retagged.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that "binary" (a bunch of bytes--period) is in contrast to something such as "plain-text" (a bunch of bytes representing plain characters in a particular character encoding). I believe all files and communication streams would fall into one of those two, although technically a text file is just a particular kind of binary file.

You do have to know the encoding of the plain-text file (legacy cp1252, unicode utf8, etc.), or auto-detect it, as most web browsers try to do.

In other words, if opening it in Notepad shows gobbledegook, it's binary,or you picked the wrong encoding/font.

Comment: Right, but what's the point of having it as a tag?

Answer (score 0):

[binary](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/binary) may not be required, but maybe what we want is [binary-execution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/binary-execution), it gives the added advantage of [executable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/executable)  too. And sound more aesthetic than [executable-execution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/executable-execution). I've just gone plain mad.